# Hpw to add sl number to the generated csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, append, writer

```
data=query to fetch data from MySQL with for loop .
fileName="abcd/2022"
fieldNames = [
        "SL NUMBER"
        "NAME",
        "PLACE",
        "AGE"
]

with open(fileName,append_write) as csvfile: 
                        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldNames)
                        writer.writeheader()
                        writer.writerows(data)
```

After generating csv file its look like this,

```
SL NUMBER NAME  PLACE     AGE
           xyz  delhi     15
           pqr  mumbai    23
           lmn  karnataka 21
```

csv is generated for  "NAME","PLACE","AGE" these columns and all datas is coming fine with new lines.now the requirement is for **"SL NUMBER" need to be auto incremented based on entries** how can i achieve that.  Thanks for inputs

Comment: post a fragment of `data`

Comment: in for loop using  +1 for SL NUMBER its achieved. but is there any way adding index at writer method.
Now  inside for loop sl_no=0 SL NUMBER =sl_no + 1 is working